# How do ligands bind to and release from receptors?

Tags: neuroscience, cell-signaling

I'm wondering exactly how ligands bind to and release from receptors. Until recently I presumed ligands were attracted to receptors through electrostatic forces with no chemical interaction involved, and that catabolic enzymes (MAO, AChE) were simply present in the extracellular fluid. I hadn't given much thought as to how they disengage, but assumed ligands were brushed off by the extracellular fluid.

However, recently, I was reading about acetylcholinergic signaling and how it can be disrupted by, and I've come to realize is that everything I thought I knew about neurotransmission may be wrong. What I've read suggests this (article linked below):

- AChE is membrane-bound
- AChE is part of the AChR, or just happens to be is close enough proximity that the AChE can catabolize the ligand while bound to the receptor
- The AChR attracts ACh's positively-charged amine, which brings the acetyl group within range of AChE's reactive alcohol group. This alcohol group cleaves the acetyl group from ACh
- It is not until the acetyl group is cleaved that the ligand disengages from the receptor

My questions:

- Is all of this correct?
- Are the AChR and AChE distinct? If so, how can both simultaneously interact with a single molecule given their much larger size? If not, why are they ever spoken of as different?
- Is this sort of catabolism-mediated disengagement the case with other neurotransmitters?
- Where can I read more about this, and what is this sort of interaction called? It's been difficult finding information on this.

Here's the source I was reading on ACh transmission:
http://www.umich.edu/~essen/html/web_mod/cobra/respiration_detailed.html

Comment: Look for the Coursera course "Drugs and the Brain" and see when it's offered next.  It touches on a lot of these issues and more, and I think you would find it fascinating.  Meanwhile, I'll see if I can answer some of this a bit later.

Comment: [This](http://www.amazon.com/Molecular-Neuropharmacology-Foundation-Clinical-Neuroscience/dp/0071481273/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1406804539&sr=8-1&keywords=molecular+neuropharmacology+a+foundation+for+clinical+neuroscience&dpPl=1) is the text used in the course.  It's gone up a lot in price, but it's very helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a biology question.

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr normally I would be inclined to agree with you, but Chuck's comment suggests that this could be a border-case between bio and our site.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev That's what close votes are for, I suppose, but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with any behavioral variables at all, so I'm maintaining my vote. I might have been more inclined to agree if Chuck or another trusted user had attempted an answer rather than a quick comment.

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr I've been pretty busy over the last couple of years.  I can't promise I will be able to answer at this time, but I think questions like these should be "grandfathered" in.  While I respect and admire the work that you've put into the site thus far, the Area 51 numbers aren't everything.

Comment: @ChuckSherrington Thank you, and likewise. The close vote failed; let's leave it at that. :)

Comment: Maybe @AliceD can take a look? This is not really something I can answer.